# What class of differential equations are these?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes

In my research I came across the type of differential equation described below. I've looked in introductory ODE and PDE books for a treatment of this type of equations, but I had no success. So any insight as to what class of ODE's these are or any references that deal with them would be much appreciated.

Let $y(t,x)$ be a scalar quantity that depends on a temporal ($t$) and spatial variable ($x \in \Omega$).
The dynamics of $y$ are given by
$$
\frac{\partial y(t,x)}{\partial t} = a(x) \bar y(t) + b(x) y(t,x),
$$
where $\bar y$ is the space average ($\bar y = \int_{\Omega} y(t,x) dx$), a(x) is a parameter, and b(x) is a parameter.

---

Additional rambling (not part of the question, but I think it's interesting):

What is throwing me off is that the pointwise dynamics depend on the space average variable $\bar y$ (almost like there is a diffusion of spatial information even though there are no differential operators). Specifically,I'd like to show that $|| y(t,x)||_{\mathcal{L^2}} \rightarrow 0$ exponentially fast, but when computing the time derivative of
$|| y(t,x)||_{\mathcal{L^2}}^2$ one gets a term of the form
$$
\big[\int_\Omega a(x) y(t,x) dx \big]\bar y(t), 
$$
which is sign indefinite and thus problematic. This almost suggests that the space averaged term can "destabilize" the dynamics.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: The keyword is “non-local”.

Comment: In principle this average can absolutely destabilize things. Consider for instance a situation where the average of the initial data is $1$, $\Omega=[-1,1]$, $b$ is just zero, and $a$ is the sign function. Then the average is $1$ but the derivative of the average is zero, so you have linear growth. With some tweaking you could create a problem even when $b$ is strictly negative all the time.